# Creating JQuery div class filter not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a filter with JQuery that hides all div's and then only shows div's depending on a class inside it called "brand", I managing to get it to hide all div's however it will not show the ones matching the class.

The alert I have added inside the statement is showing so I think it may be something to do with the parent show, has anyone got any ideas?

The html:

```
<div class="section-link" id="section-tooltip" data-content="Popup with option trigger" rel="popover" data-placement="right" title="" data-original-title="">
    <div class="section-features" style="display: none;">
        <p><i class="icon-star"></i> protective, waterproof lid</p>
        <p><i class="icon-star"></i> enhanced wooden coating</p>
        <p><i class="icon-star"></i> long lasting materials</p>
        <p><i class="icon-star"></i> 2 year warranty</p>
        <p><i class="icon-star"></i> includes durable bag</p>
    </div>

    <div class="brand tp" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div class="price" style="display: none;"> £47.99</div>
    <a href="Garden-Games-Picnic-Table-Sandpit-6407.html">
        <img src="picnic_table_sandpit.jpg" title="Garden Games Picnic Table Sandpit" alt="Garden Games Picnic Table Sandpit" width="220">
        <h3 align="center">Garden Games Picnic Table Sandpit</h3>
        <p align="center">
            <span> was: £69.99</span>
            <span> Now:  £47.99</span>
            <span class="button">More Info</span>
        </p>
        </a>
    <a name="a6407"></a>
</div>
```

/\ there are about 20 div's like this with different brand classes example class="brand garden"

The Js:

```
function brand(string){
    var brand = string;
    $('.section-link').hide();
    if ($('.section-link').children('.brand').hasClass(brand)) {
        alert(brand);
        $(this).parent().show();
    }
}
```

I am also testing via the chrome url bar `javascript: brand("tp");`

Any help greatly appreciated,
Simon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use multiple selector here because you need to fetch `.brand` elements which also have the specified class

```
function brand(string){
    var brand = string;
    $('.section-link').hide();
    $('.section-link').children('.brand.' + brand).parent().show();
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XBJED/)